# KMLLayer Infowindow

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml

I am trying to add a KML layer to ESRI javascript project. That part is easy enough.

I want the KML file to appear, but do not want any infowindow to display for items within that KML. All that I want is the kml image on the map as shown below.

[image: Correct Display]

I had it working as I described using the following dojo.connect code... but then read that this method is deprecated, so I am trying to make an I made the changes to support a kml.on("load"...) style event.

With the dojo connect function the kml layer appears without the ability to click on that layer and have an infowindow display. This is the result that I want to achieve by using the kml.on event function.

However, once I changed my code from this:

```
dojo.connect(kml, 'onLoad', function(lyr) {    
  var layers = lyr.getLayers();    
  dojo.forEach(layers, function(lyr) {    
      lyr.setInfoTemplate(null);    
  });    
});
```

to

```
kml.on("load", function(lyr) {  
  var layers = lyr.getLayers();  
  array.forEach(layers, function(lyr) {  
     lyr.setInfoTemplate(null);  
  });  
});
```

This new kml.on code is now causing the entire kml shape to no longer display in the map. As shown in the image below.

[image: Failed To Load KML at All]

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is solved. Needed to use lyr.layer.getLayers() and then setInfoTemplate to null on each of those layers.

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by using `lyr.layer.getLayers()` instead of `lyr.getLayers();` and then setInfoTemplate to null on each of those layers.

```
   //On loading the kml file
   kml.on("load", function(lyr){
      //Extract all of the layers from within the KML 
      var layers = lyr.layer.getLayers();
      //For each of those layers, 
      //1. Set click event to re-center the map to original point
      //2. Set the infoTemplate for each layer to null
      // That way whenever the kml layer is clicked there is no infowindow
      // to display to the users.
      array.forEach(layers, function(l) {
        l.on("click", centerMap);
        l.setInfoTemplate(null);
      });
    });
```

Comment: can you please comment (explain) your code so that non-coders would be able to understand the code better (and more likely get up votes) thanks